# Highcharts irregular data code not working

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to visualize data with irregular xAxis values. My code is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                $('#chart').highcharts({
        chart: {'zoomType': 'x', 'panKey': 'shift', 'height': 350, 'panning': 'true', 'renderTo': 'chart', 'type': 'spline'},
        title: {'text': 'My Title'},
        xAxis: {'title': {'text': 'xAxis Label'}},
        yAxis: {'title': {'text': 'yAxis Label'}},
        series: [{'data': [['0', '0.125376631311'], ['857', '0.112562080094'], ['1240', '0.0808275217022'], ['2077', '0.0886424104183'], ['2507', '0.233281510574'], ['3719', '0.0541587946179'], ['4411', '0.0537776511462'], ['5023', '0.186131479895'], ['5644', '0.0428443736756'], ['5988', '0.0981346287359'], ['6873', '0.0129177555514'], ['7514', '0.0693567928808'], ['7730', '0.142703979605'], ['7961', '0.00800173174274'], ['8620', '0.0397936682852'], ['10324', '0.0366131250325'], ['11052', '0.0721536161288'], ['11907', '0.128416134583'], ['12228', '0.0743749452385'], ['12252', '0.129584406737'], ['12396', '0.143764961393'], ['12434', '0.0374909627087'], ['12727', '0.345151430348'], ['12776', '0.0395462360018'], ['13039', '0.291435438087'], ['13086', '0.0217096164496'], ['13337', '0.113148058355'], ['13360', '0.0852778748282'], ['13544', '0.0476490547565'], ['13571', '0.24543126774'], ['13739', '0.54243341547'], ['13980', '0.777735452126'], ['14025', '0.21217100436'], ['14886', '0.066454213712'], ['14919', '0.154569639775'], ['15266', '0.189223328635'], ['15424', '0.713863165958'], ['16144', '0.0481496898997'], ['16221', '0.115893165229'], ['16700', '0.945624060926'], ['16771', '0.945624060926'], ['16904', '0.945624060926'], ['17154', '0.559815328541'], ['17430', '0.0757325036102'], ['17655', '0.032155740001'], ['18320', '0.102462178624'], ['19494', '0.139796254956'], ['19753', '0.0675682807231'], ['20166', '0.286754992712'], ['20693', '0.0619359511802'], ['20957', '0.321809831002'], ['21262', '0.0790114610937'], ['21799', '0.00111416063243'], ['23145', '0.645609347332'], ['23550', '0.0101418835789'], ['24203', '0.155855418314'], ['24709', '0.30302742197'], ['24995', '0.0714466155141'], ['25302', '0.106988301229'], ['25732', '0.0625301329162'], ['26114', '0.188789413925'], ['26171', '0.157265601144'], ['26238', '0.157265601144']], 'name': 'PMC3933031'}, {'data': [['0', '0.0157945769539'], ['417', '0.112571749166'], ['821', '0.0614273522652'], ['1429', '0.156664619076'], ['1627', '0.0363440267717'], ['3222', '0.0484172953864'], ['4778', '0.000636310022659'], ['6014', '0.19320464809'], ['6244', '0.0097701661134'], ['7924', '0.88098456556'], ['8010', '0.88098456556'], ['8182', '0.334768570161'], ['10378', '0.687610876665'], ['10448', '0.367181095193'], ['12671', '0.264634039808'], ['13758', '0.0536130673189'], ['15004', '0.264351808298'], ['16277', '0.196281095865'], ['17825', '0.122301161181'], ['19547', '0.0230174076364'], ['20627', '0.178090355517'], ['21174', '0.10440720161'], ['22057', '0.24116580962'], ['22102', '0.0835967088207']], 'name': 'PMC4449985'}, {'data': [['0', '0.00692681303398'], ['487', '0.0768650114316'], ['817', '0.112299128425'], ['1228', '0.0671122722431'], ['1386', '0.095078517595'], ['1779', '0.0575096848386'], ['2397', '0.061203734551'], ['2948', '0.1287051666'], ['3241', '0.0587343727129'], ['3493', '0.0680418559407'], ['4099', '0.52630074785'], ['4428', '0.0781910074632'], ['4638', '0.214913872044'], ['4903', '0.0332518976994'], ['5351', '0.0443151910882'], ['5837', '0.65925447051'], ['6253', '0.0600737231895'], ['6526', '0.0278622187257'], ['7020', '0.00289528325582'], ['7522', '0.0729018993257'], ['7955', '0.000194292220781'], ['8332', '0.12844878588'], ['8799', '0.0143362841574'], ['9342', '0.120883293069'], ['9833', '0.168926623735'], ['10093', '0.046570514056'], ['10705', '0.0971180236755'], ['11097', '0.0932849979927'], ['11284', '0.111189874023'], ['11521', '0.0956022362464'], ['12092', '0.08206996573'], ['12445', '0.125605050881'], ['12897', '0.0385257556023'], ['13335', '0.0312544747698'], ['13654', '0.000113035583808'], ['14109', '0.022635365522'], ['14598', '0.118325244411'], ['15388', '0.158130667077'], ['15547', '0.079123842175'], ['16064', '0.118487612658'], ['17059', '0.163789440097'], ['17132', '0.158399973682'], ['17722', '0.315089417501'], ['17833', '0.0400059410025'], ['18107', '0.0930526934059'], ['18303', '0.317522808048'], ['18588', '0.0393405896056'], ['18744', '0.805946903087'], ['18839', '0.805946903087'], ['19338', '0.00433217908227'], ['20131', '0.160540811222'], ['20349', '0.00915589187098'], ['20675', '0.0274518327636'], ['21075', '0.0531784940441'], ['22070', '0.0271351891745'], ['22663', '0.0420037604492'], ['22876', '0.266433221789'], ['23128', '0.867552859336'], ['23657', '0.0268458861584'], ['24020', '0.234119653761'], ['24274', '0.000357355644665'], ['24642', '0.268837574263'], ['24898', '0.129518705924'], ['25348', '0.0874541528632'], ['25748', '0.163266754776'], ['26238', '0.0787655352028'], ['26905', '0.193684448309']], 'name': 'PMC4189865'}]
    });
});
```

I adapted the code from here http://www.highcharts.com/demo/spline-irregular-time/grid.

However, the graph is not even appearing. Can someone tell me what is going wrong here?

Comment: *this is not working as expected*...In what way? What do you expect and how does what you see differ?

Comment: @Liam Sorry about the ambiguity

Comment: Have you checked your console? Do you have any errors?

Comment: @Liam I tried a debugger online. It reports that there are no errors. I am wondering whether I am accessing the API correctly because I have another graph that works, one with regular data

Comment: Check the console in your [browsers debugging tools](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/988363/how-can-i-debug-my-javascript-code). I.e. https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console

Comment: @Liam Thanks. I got an error finally. Says I should pass numbers instead of strings.

Comment: Can you add the exact error into the question? Your data your sending to highcharts is incorrect. But I'm not a highchart expert unfortunately

Comment: The reason of that is using strings instead of numbers in data array. Istead of [['0', '0.125376631311'], ['857', '0.112562080094'], should be [[0, 0.125376631311], [857, 0.112562080094]...]